# Testing `approve` function

Tags: solidity, truffle-test, erc-20-approve

I would like to test a contract where I use the `approve` function of an ERC20 token.
Is there any test suite that allows doing that?

truffle? hardhat?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can use chai with both truffle and hardhat

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai